# How can I validate two date fields against each other and current day?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to validate an HTML form field:

1. The start date must be before the end date
2. Both dates must be not in the past.

Here is my form inputs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateIsBefore = false;
  var dateInPast = false;

  $('#end_date').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($('#start_date').val() < $('#end_date').val()) {
      dateIsBefore = true;
    } else {
      $('#message').html('Start date must not be after end date').css('color', 'red');
      dateIsBefore = false;
    }
  });

  $('#submitRequest').click(function(e) {
    if (!dateIsBefore) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" />

<input class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" />
<br/>
<button type="submit" id="submitRequest" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Request</button> <span id='message'></span>
```

I use type Date, so not sure if I need to replace `/` before comparing. Also I am not sure how I would be able to check if the dates are in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: *I use type Date* - there's no date types in your code, only strings.  You need to convert `$("#id").val()` to a date first, then compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `momentjs` library, this library is popular for handle date time.

In your code, you need `set $('#message').html('');` in case valid

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateIsBefore = false;
  var dateInPast = false;

  $('#end_date').on('keyup', function() {
    var start_date = moment($('#start_date').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
    var end_date = moment($('#end_date').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
   
    if ( start_date < end_date) {
      dateIsBefore = true;
      $('#message').html('');
    } else {
      $('#message').html('Start date must not be after end date').css('color', 'red');
      dateIsBefore = false;
    }
  });

  $('#submitRequest').click(function(e) {
    if (!dateIsBefore) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<input class="form-control" id="start_date" name="start_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" />

<input class="form-control" id="end_date" name="end_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" />
<br/>
<button type="submit" id="submitRequest" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Request</button> <span id='message'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare the input's values directly in your condition. These values are Strings and  as string they get compared [lexographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).
To compare the values as Dates you have to simply create a new Date Object from the inputs value String and compare those:

```
 if(new Date($('#start_date').val()) > new Date($('#end_date').val())) {
    alert('End has to be after start');
 }
```

To take it a step further, you could reset the inputs value to `null` if the condition returns `true`, that way your input has no value, and since it has the `required` Attribute, the additional check in your submit gets redundant and can be deleted.

```
 if(new Date($('#start_date').val()) > new Date($('#end_date').val())) {
    alert('End has to be after start');
    $(this).val(null);
 }
```

*Side note:*

I would rather use the `change` event instead of the `keyup` event, to validate your input. You have alot of unnessecary runs and probably even errors when you use the `keyup`event and check before a valid date string is entered.

Comment: `change` is definitely better than `keyup` - but you might also want to consider `input` event

Comment: AFAIK the `change` and `input` events are identical on date inputs, and i think it adds just a bit of readabliltity to use the `change`event.